# What does "git fetch -f origin remote-master:local-master" do? Any difference with "git fetch origin +remote-master:local-master"?

Tags: git

The question is as the title. I know the general idea of "git fetch", but just want to confirm, what happen if my local-master branch is not an ancestor of the remote-master, will "git fetch -f origin remote-master:local-master" delete all my local-master, and then copy over the remote-master branch?

Another question is, is "-f" equivalent to "+"?

Comment: The fetch won't delete anything; it will just point the `local-master` head to the fetched object identified by `remote-master`. If that was wrong to do, you fix `local-master` to point back to what it was before.

Comment: I can't deduce any difference between `-f` and `+`.  A fast forward from A to B can occur if A is an ancestor of B; it's the same.

Comment: @Kaz, if fetch won't delete anything, then where does the old (before the fetch)  content of the local-master go? Say local-master points to A before the fetch. A is not an ancestor of B. After the fetch (with +), local-master would point to B. Then where is A?

Comment: @Kaz: the only difference between `-f` and `+`-on-a-refspec is that each + is local to that particular refspec, while `-f` is global across all refspecs (on the one command-run).

Comment: @torek That's what I thought; it's just documented so strangely. Different wording, and no connection is made between the two. I mean, just document `-f` and then say that `+` has the effect of `-f`, scoped to this ref only.

Answer (score 0):

`git help fetch` says:

```
   -f, --force
       When git fetch is used with <rbranch>:<lbranch> refspec, it refuses to
       update the local branch <lbranch> unless the remote branch <rbranch> it
       fetches is a descendant of <lbranch>. This option overrides that check.

[...]
If the optional plus + is used, the local ref is updated even if it does
not result in a fast-forward update.
```

This indicates that both do indeed the same.

If you want to be really sure be free to look at the [source](https://github.com/git/git).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one fundamental thing here.  A `git fetch` *never* deletes *any* objects from your repository.  It may, however, change *references* in such a way that objects *can* be deleted from your repository.  This is where the danger, when there is any danger, lies.

#### Objects and references

In Git, an *object* is any one of four object types in your repository.  The four object types are `commit`, `tree`, `blob` (file), and `tag` (annotated tag).  These objects are literally how Git stores all of your content.  If it's not in an object, it's not "content"—at most, it's some sort of auxiliary information *about* content instead.

To name an object, you give Git its hash ID (`a234567...`).  This ID never changes: it always uniquely represents that particular object.  Moreover, every Git in the universe calculates the *same* hash ID for the same object—which seems a bit like magic, but is how Git implements the "distributed" part of being a Distributed Version Control System.

Commit objects are especially interesting here because each commit objects name other, earlier commit objects.  Specifically, each commit has zero or more *parent* commits.  Most commits have exactly one parent; most *merge commits* have exactly two parents (but more are allowed); and except in a new empty repository, there's always one at least one *root commit* that has no parents.  (Obviously, the very first commit you make cannot have a previous commit, since there were no commits before then.)

The problem with hash IDs is that they are large, unwieldy, ugly, and un-memorable.  What is `ed4f38babf3d81693a68d06cd0f5872093c009f6`?  It's Git version 2.1.1, but who can remember that?  Well, *Git* can remember that *for* us, using a *tag*: a reference name.  The tag `v2.1.1`, in a Git repository for Git, translates into that hash (which is actually the ID of a tag object but the tag object then points to the commit object, so it's just as good—or maybe even better: the tag object *is* content; see below).

*References* are these more-memorable names, which also store Git's internal hash IDs.  References are not content, and hence not version-controlled.  They are just auxiliary information *about* content.  They're pretty important to us humans since branch and tag names are two forms of references, and we like to have Git get us the content, by branch and tag names.  But they also serve one other crucial function in Git: they *protect* objects by making the objects *reachable*.

#### Reachability

*Reachability* is best though-of using commits.  We start with a branch name like `master`.  This translates, in Git, into a hash ID.  The hash ID is called the *tip commit* of the branch.  We can, obviously, find that commit: read `master`, turn it into a hash ID, and read the commit.  We've reached the tip of `master`!

Because each commit remembers its parents, though, we can use the tip commit to find *all its earlier commits*.  The parent of the tip of `master`—or both parents, if it's a typical two-parent merge commit—is right there, in that commit.  We get the ID (or both IDs) and use that to look up the previous commit.  We've reached the commit—or two commits—one step back from the tip of `master`!

That commit, or those commits, have IDs for earlier commits.  We can use those to read all the commits that are *two* steps back: we've reached the commits two steps back from the tip of `master`!

Those commits have more IDs for earlier commits.  We use them to read all the commits that are *three* steps back ... and so on, all the way back to the root commit.  Wow, we've found every commit on branch `master`, all the way back to the root!  We've *reached* all those commits.

What about commits *not* on `master`?  Well, suppose there are some commits on `develop`.  We read the branch-name `develop` to get its tip commit, and read that commit to get its one-step-back commit(s), and read those commits to get the two-steps-back commits, and so on, all the way back to the root.  We've *reached* all those commits (note that we've reached the root twice now).

Meanwhile, if there are some commits on `feature` that aren't on either of the other branches, that's no problem: we can reach them from their other names.  And that's *reachability* in a nutshell: we start with all the names, which translate to object IDs.  We use those object IDs to find the objects, and use the objects' contents to find other objects.  Everything we find is *reachable*.

If there are objects in the Git repository that we *don't* find in this way, these objects are *unreachable*.  They have been abandoned, and they are fit to be removed: *garbage collected*, using `git gc`.  This garbage collection process is the only normal way of removing anything from Git.

There is one extra twist with references: Git has a feature called *reflogs*, which are log files that keep track of the previous hash IDs stored in each reference.  Reflogs are optional, and reflog entries eventually expire—the default is to expire them after 30 or 90 days—so they normally only offer *temporary* protection, but that's normally what we want anyway.  Normally, if we want to *keep* an object, we make sure that it either has a direct reference—such as a branch or tag name—or is in a chain of commits that has a reference.

And *now* we can answer your main question!

#### Git's `fetch`

The `fetch` command works by communicating with the other Git to:

1. Find out which objects are in the other repository that are not in your repository.  Fetch brings (some or all of) these objects over as needed.  (I say this like it's easy, when in fact there is a bunch of informatics theory involved, but for our purposes it *is* easy, because `git fetch` just does it for us.)
2. Get its idea of the objects identified by its references (its branches, tags, notes, and so on).  This is actually needed to implement step 1; but *after* step 1 is finished, your Git then writes this information into one or two places.

In this case, you've told your Git to find out about their Git's `remote-master` (because your refspec was either `remote-master:local-master` or `+remote-master:local-master`).  That is, the `<src>` part of the refspec is `remote-master`.  This name is not fully qualified, so your Git will wind up treating this as a tag if it matches a tag, or as a branch if it matches a branch.  If it matches neither, this will just fail.  To control *which kind* of reference it can match, you can spell it out completely (`refs/heads/remote-master` for instance).  Let's just assume that it matches a branch here.

Note that this branch (or tag) name maps to some hash value.  Use `git ls-remote origin` to see the names and hash values available on remote `origin`; it will be pretty obvious which name-and-hash-value your Git will pick up.

In this case, you've also given your Git a non-empty `<dst>` part of the refspec.  That will matter in just a moment.

The one place your Git always writes the information from step 2 is `FETCH_HEAD`.  So your `FETCH_HEAD` file will acquire a hash, and some extra information that your `git fetch` command leaves behind intended for use by the very oldest versions of `git pull`.

The *second* place your Git *may* write information from step 2 is from the `<dst>` part of your refspec.

If you don't give `git fetch` a `<dst>` part at all—e.g., `git fetch origin remote-master`—your Git tends not to write the information anywhere else.  For step 2, it may just write to `FETCH_HEAD` and then terminate.  This is complicated in ways that are Git-version-dependent.<sup>1</sup>

If you *do* give `git fetch` a `<dst>` part, the `<dst>` part can be fully-qualified (`refs/heads/local-master`, `refs/remotes/origin/local-master`, `refs/tags/local-master`, and so on) or not-fully-qualified.  If it is not-fully-qualified, Git attempts to intuit the correct qualification; in this particular case, we're assuming `remote-master` is a branch name (`refs/heads/remote-master`) in the other Git so `local-master` will become a branch name (`refs/heads/local-master`) in your own Git.

Just because you have a `<dst>` part, though, does not mean your `<dst>` reference will be updated!  If you *don't* set a force flag, your Git will do some checking.  Specifically, your Git will first check whether you have such a reference.  If not, everything is easy: your Git will create the local reference, with the corresponding hash.  If you *do* already have it, though, then—and again, this is for "no force flag":

- For a branch, your Git will refuse to update your local branch if the label change is not a fast-forward move.
- For a tag, your Git will refuse to update it at all, unless your Git is older than 1.8.2, in which case it applies the branch rules instead.<sup>2</sup>

This is where the `-f` and `+` flags comes in.  The `+` in front of a refspec sets the force flag for that particular refspec.  With the force flag set, `git fetch` updates the local refspec even if the default rules say not to update it.  The `-f` option sets the force flag for *every* refspec on the command line, so with `-f`, `git fetch` again updates forcefully.

Now let's look at your question one last time:

> What happen if my local-master branch is not an ancestor of the remote-master, will "git fetch -f origin remote-master:local-master" delete all my local-master, and then copy over the remote-master branch?

Since you have the `-f` flag, your local reference will be updated, even if the change is not a fast-forward operation (i.e., your local reference is not an ancestor of the incoming remote hash ID).  But you have the order of operations backwards: `git fetch` will already have brought over all the objects.  Moreover, `git fetch` will write the branch tip ID to the file `FETCH_HEAD` whether or not it updates `local-master`—and even if `git fetch` updates the `local-master` reference, potentially exposing some commit object(s) to the garbage collector because they have become unreferenced, *still* nothing is as-yet deleted.  If `local-master` has a reflog, the reflog will protect those objects for 30 more days by default.

> Another question is, is `-f` equivalent to `+`?

The `-f` flag simply has the effect of adding `+` to each command-line refspec.  If you give only one refspec, they are exactly the same.  If you provide multiple refspecs, `-f` essentially adds `+` to each one (if it's not there already).

---

<sup>1</sup>Specifically, in Git version 1.8.4 or later, Git will "opportunistically update" remote-tracking branches.  If you have a configuration line that reads `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`—usually you will—your Git will, having read `refs/heads/remote-master` from `origin`, update your `refs/remotes/origin/remote-master`.  This does require that that configuration line exist.  Note that it has a force flag (`+`) in its refspec!

<sup>2</sup>I *think* `notes` and other references work like tags, but have not tested this.  The default is not to copy anything but branches and tags anyway, except for fetch-mirror configurations, which are controlled by `fetch` configuration lines that should always have a force flag set.  Either way the question simply does not occur.